# foreach loop with textbox names

Tags: c#, foreach

how do i make a foreach loop from this, i want to change the size only of the textboxes that ends with txt2

```
        br1txt2.Size = new Size(27, 20);
        br2txt2.Size = new Size(27, 20);
        br3txt2.Size = new Size(27, 20);
        br4txt2.Size = new Size(27, 20);
        br5txt2.Size = new Size(27, 20);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Size newSize = new Size(27, 20);
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if (c is TextBox && c.Name.EndsWith("txt2"))
   {
      c.Size = newSize;
   }
}
```

Comment: so just test for c.Name.EndsWith("txt2")

Comment: Maybe you should check if c is a textbox?

Comment: changed the "and" to || and it builds just fine
        if (c is TextBox || c.Name.EndsWith("txt2"))

Comment: My bad - don't use || that means 'or' - see my edit.  Use '&&' which is AND.

Answer (score 0):

haven't done any winforms for years, but I think this might do the trick

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes = GetTextBoxes() //Get your textboxes from wherever
Size newSize = new Size(27, 20);
foreach (Control c in textBoxes.Where(c=>c.Name.EndsWith("txt2")))
{
   c.Size = newSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox[] tBoxesForSizeChange = new TextBox[2] {br1txt2, br2txt2 };
Size newSize = new Size(27, 20);

foreach(TextBox tBox in tBoxesForSizeChange)
{
   tBox.Size = newSize;
}
```

The code might not compile.
But, I hope it gives you idea to build further.